# django filtering based on foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to get all the orders except orders with order_type =14 (order table has a foreign key reference to order_type and batch tables) when i am calling the url.
Please help me to know the solution.

```
#models.py

class Batch(models.Model):
        batchnum = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        otp= models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    reqnum = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    batch= models.ForeignKey(Batch, db_index=True,related_name='results', on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True, blank=True)
    order_status = models.ForeignKey('DotOrderStatus', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='dot_order_status',default=1)
    order_type = models.ForeignKey('DotOrderType', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='dot_order_type',default=10)
    slno = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    customer_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    contact = models.BigIntegerField( null=True, blank=True)


url:localhost:8000/api/v1/batch/id
```

where '/id' is batch id

Please help me to know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` in order not to include the order with ID 14:

```
batch_orders = batch.results.all().exclude(order_type__id=14)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks..but we have no foreign key reference of order on batch model.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov there is a typo, i think it is order_type batch.results.all().exclude(order_type__id=14)

Comment: we have no foreign key references for batch order.order_type is defined in order model.we have to filter orders from batch viewset.

Comment: @jsk for a given batch object, batch.results.all() will give all the orders for that batch. And you can do filter/exclude on the same using order fields.

Comment: @jsk you don't have to have a foreign key. You already have a reverse foreign key. Try the update.

Comment: @jsk if the answer helped, can you please accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use exclude to exclude order_type id 14 and use filter to filter by batch id

```
Order.objects.exclude(order_type__id=14).filter(batch__id=id)
```

Comment: there is no need to use '\_\_' (double underscore). "\_" (single underscore) will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this.

```
Order.objects.filter(batch_id=id).exclude(order_type_id=14)
```